# Facebook tab redirect with header('location:'.$url);

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, api, redirect

I'm working on an application TAB for facebook. In theory I wanted to create a redirect between fans and non fans (the classic fangate) ... but I have no problem with the database!

```
----- First example, work only with HTTPS and not HTTP :/
$fan = 'https://website.com/fan.html'; 
$nofan = 'https://website.com/nofan.html';

----- Second example i get it form database and doesn't work :@
$fan = $app_data[5]; //if I print this > https://website.com/fan.html
$nofan = $app_data[6]; //if I print this > https://website.com/nofan.html
```

Then i put it in:

```
if (1<2) {
echo header( "Location:".$fan); exit;}
else { 
echo header( "Location:".$nofan); exit;}
```

Thanks for your attention. I hope I explained well and look forward to suggestions ..

SOLVED: as you can see here > http://jsfiddle.net/x2F8s/1/ The php header location based redirect doesnt work inside iframes O.o  STRANGE :O

Comment: ...any ideas? Questions?

Comment: The websites in your example are just dont-show-in-iframe protected. Check out this discussion: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/2haFgrq50Po

Comment: I understand this now.  http://jsfiddle.net/x2F8s/1/ Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this

```
if (1<2) {
 header( "Location: ".$fan.""); die();}
else { 
header( "Location: ".$nofan); die();}
```

Comment: works for you? or still need help

Comment: it's work with normal browser but not in facebook... I'm doing some the tests.

Comment: Cause it might require authentication to get there.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x2F8s/ the problem was with the iframe redirect support..

Comment: Hi...there an example: http://jsfiddle.net/x2F8s/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x2F8s/2/ try

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I knew how to do it with javascript ... but the problem remains for users who do not have JavaScript enabled or does not want it ..

Comment: Is this even possible:D? Now everyone uses js :\ Good luck

Comment: I know...but it is a requirement of my project D: